VS Code zooming in sensitivity
I was using VS Code for like 3 years and everything was fine, but for some reason today when I opened up VS Code and open my code and tried to zoom in, I had to scroll like 7-8 whole scrolls to zoom in to the right amount. Usually I had to just scroll one or two times.
I tried looking in settings or to find some extensions to customize code zoom, but I didn't find anything useful.
How could I modifly the level of zooming in in code with scrolling it?

Did you change your mouse wheel settings in the OS?

I eventualy fixed it, somewhat. Buy "zoom in" i meant how many thimes I have to scroll with my finger with sctoll whele, and for some reason it's "sensitivety" was way lower, like, I will scroll the entire length of my scroll whele, and the code that I had open will get zoomed in only like 5%, that didnt happend before so I didn't know what has happend. But I just pressed the CTRL , +  and zoomed in the entire window (tabs, taskbar  etc.) and now it better

@CofiShachou Hi Cofi. One of your questions was migrated to Database Administrators Stack Exchange: https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/338881/, I notice it also received some upvotes and reputation there. You'd have more reputation at dba admins than you have here if you signed up as a user there. Please check out this answer to your question that was migrated to there.

As far as i know theres no configuration for sensivity to scroll zoom in/out
But you can turn on zoom in / out in visual studio code by mouse scroll by adding "editor.mouseWheelZoom": true, to your settings.json which can be opened like press ctrl + P (on windows) then type in search bar >settings.json and press enter
After this steps you should be able to zoom code in and out by pressing Ctrl(on windows) and use mouse scroll
If you like to scale whole text in visual studio code you can press combination
(on windows) ctrl + to up scale and ctrl - to down scale
